# Items appearing on Android Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_sign_up"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mastermindcorp.alibdeir.salawat.signUpActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/pattern">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/LL">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/LL">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/emailET"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is how it shows:

[image]

Java:

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
```

As you can see, the text is in the toolbar and the EditText is missing. This is extremely irritating. I've tried a lot of things and searched everyone, and I couldn't find anything.

Comment: That's because your RelativeLayout with your items is laying over your LinearLayout

Comment: Use LinearLayout as your parent layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing the `LinearLayout` that wraps the Toolbar and setting my content's `RelativeLayout` to be below the toolbar with `android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"`.

Answer (score 0):

Linear layout like other says work as well, but you can also try if this works.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_sign_up"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.mastermindcorp.alibdeir.salawat.signUpActivity"
android:background="@drawable/pattern">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@id/my_toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/emailET"
    android:hint="@string/email"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```